# Oracle trigger to call Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an SP that needs to be called by an "after update" trigger. This Sp writes out a document to the mounted oracle directory for the host application to pick up. The SP has the following parameters :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE test_sp_mbinfo
(out_status OUT VARCHAR2,
out_dir OUT VARCHAR2,
in_contract IN VARCHAR2)
```

The in_contract parameter would be sent in by the triggering event. The trigger code i have so far that i have a hard time compiling is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mbinfo_trig
AFTER UPDATE OF tsta_cncontst ON kndtsta
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF (:new.tsta_cncontst IN ('02','06'))
THEN
 test_sp_mbinfo(:new.tsta_cncclipu);
END IF;

END
;
```

How do i pass in the 2 out parameters to make the process work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could declare two local variables in the trigger and pass those for the `OUT` parameter. The question then becomes whether you care about the returned values, and if so what to do with them.